# Hibernate EntityInterceptor not intercepting

Tags: hibernate, spring, interceptor

I am developing a web application using Spring, Hibernate and Struts. For my domain entity classes, I have 2 java.util.Date variables that I would like to set using the Hibernate Interceptor.

Every entity class has the following 2 variables that I would like to set.

private Date createDate;
private Date updateDate;

I have written the code and done the required configurations, somehow the entity never gets intercepted. The interceptor in injected into the SessionFactory using Spring. I put break points on the AuditInterceptor class. They never got invoked. Code and configurations are below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@Entity  
  @Table(name = "person")  
  public class Person {  
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false)
    private Date createDate;  
    @Column(name = "update_date", nullable = false)  
    private Date updateDate;  
    @Column(name = "version_number")  
    @Version  
    private int versionNumber;  
    // getters and setters      
  }

public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {    
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id,  
            Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,  
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException{  
        setValue(currentState, propertyNames, "updateDate", new Date());  
        return true;  
    }  
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,  
            String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException{  
        setValue(state, propertyNames, "createDate", new Date());  
        setValue(state, propertyNames, "updateDate", new Date());  
        return true;  
    }  
    private void setValue(Object[] state, String[] propertyNames,  
            String propertyToSet, Object value) {  
        int index = Arrays.asList(propertyNames).indexOf(propertyToSet);  
        if (index >= 0) {  
            state[index] = value;  
        }  
    }  
}  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:properties/*.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="AuditInterceptor"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">10</prop>                
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="namingStrategy" ref="hibernateNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
            <!-- Define entities (domain objects here) -->              
                <value>com.myproj.domain.Person</value>             
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="useTransactionAwareDataSource" value="true" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />             
    </bean>

     <bean id="AuditInterceptor" class="com.myproj.interceptor.AuditInterceptor"/>  


  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="${datasource.jndi.name}" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />

    </bean>
    <bean name="hibernateNamingStrategy" class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />     
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />     
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>     
</beans>
```

Comment: Problem solved. I migrated to latest versions of Hibernate and problem was resolved. It seems like AuditInterceptor was actually not overriding the methods on EmptyInterceptor. I figured this out when I added the @Override annotation.